# Are these two binomial sums known? Proven generalization to the Hockey Stick patterns in Pascal's Triangle

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

[image: Hockey Stick patterns]

English translation. You can see the original - deprecated - in Portuguese [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/713565/revisions)

Hi, I arrived at a generalization for the Hockey Stick Patterns, from our beloved Pascal's Triangle. This generalization involves the product of pairs of binomial numbers, and therefore reassembles Vandermonde's Identity 
$$\sum \limits_{j=0}^{r}{m\choose j}{q-m\choose r-j}={q\choose r}\tag a$$

According to identity $(8)$ on the wikipedia page [Binomial Coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) we have the following looking similar formula
$$\sum \limits_{m=0}^{q}{m\choose j}{q-m\choose r-j}={q+1\choose r+1}\tag b$$

Let's get to the point!

---

As we know, the **RHS Pattern** (Right Hockey Stick) is related to columns and tells us that

$${n+1\choose p+1}=\sum \limits_{k=0}^{n-p}{n-k\choose p}\tag 1$$

Letting $d$ be the displacement - referring to columns - between $\displaystyle {n+1\choose p+1}$ and the stick/column itself - what we have today is a particular case when $d=0$ - we'll have the following for $0 \le d \le p-1$:

$${n+1\choose p+1}=\sum \limits_{k=0}^{n-p}{d+k\choose d}{n-d-k\choose p-d}\tag 2$$

In this case, we see a generalization is possible by introducting another column, the column $d$. 
And both columns are aligned to each other.

**Proof**

From $(2)$ we have

$k\gt n-p$ $\longrightarrow$ $n-d-k\lt p-d$

$$ \longrightarrow \sum \limits_{k=0}^{n-p}{d+k\choose d}{n-d-k\choose p-d}=\sum \limits_{k=0}^{n}{d+k\choose d}{n-d-k\choose p-d}$$

Letting

$m = d + k; j = d; q = n; r = p$;

And

$0\leq k\leq n$ $\longrightarrow$ $d\leq d+k\leq n+d$ $\longrightarrow$ $j\leq m\leq q+j$

So, we have

$$\sum \limits_{k=0}^{n}{d+k\choose d}{n-d-k\choose p-d}=\sum \limits_{m=j}^{q+j}{m\choose j}{q-m\choose r-j}$$

$m<j$ $\longrightarrow$ $\displaystyle{m\choose j}=0$

$m>q$ $\longrightarrow$ $\displaystyle{q-m\choose r-j}=0$

$$ \longrightarrow \sum \limits_{m=j}^{q+j}{m\choose j}{q-m\choose r-j}=\sum \limits_{m=0}^{q}{m\choose j}{q-m\choose r-j}$$

According to $(b)$,

$$\sum \limits_{m=0}^{q}{m\choose j}{q-m\choose r-j}={q+1\choose r+1}={n+1\choose p+1}$$

As expected.

---

Now let's get to the **LHS pattern** (Left Hockey Stick) - which is related to diagonals - that says

$${n+1\choose p}=\sum \limits_{k=0}^p{n-k\choose p-k}\tag 3$$

Calling $d$ the displacement - referring to diagonals - between $\displaystyle {n+1\choose p}$ and the stick/diagonal - what we have today is a particular case when $d=0$. For $0 \le d \le n-p-1$, we have

$${n+1\choose p}=\sum \limits_{k=0}^p {d+k\choose k}{n-d-k\choose p-k}\tag 4$$

Now, we see a generalization is possible by introducting another diagonal, the diagonal $d$. 
And both diagonals are aligned to each other.

**Proof**

From $(4)$ we have
$$\sum \limits_{k=0}^p {d+k\choose k}{n-d-k\choose p-k}=\sum \limits_{k=0}^p {d+k\choose d}{n-d-k\choose n-p-d}$$

$k\gt p$ $\longrightarrow$ $n-d-k\lt n-p-d$

$$ \longrightarrow \sum \limits_{k=0}^{p}{d+k\choose d}{n-d-k\choose n-p-d}=\sum \limits_{k=0}^{n}{d+k\choose d}{n-d-k\choose n-p-d}$$

Letting

$m = d + k; j = d; q = n; r = n-p$;

And

$0\leq k\leq n$ $\longrightarrow$ $d\leq d+k\leq n+d$ $\longrightarrow$ $j\leq m\leq q+j$

So, we have

$$\sum \limits_{k=0}^{n}{d+k\choose d}{n-d-k\choose n-p-d}=\sum \limits_{m=j}^{q+j}{m\choose j}{q-m\choose r-j}$$

$m<j$ $\longrightarrow$ $\displaystyle{m\choose j}=0$

$m>q$ $\longrightarrow$ $\displaystyle{q-m\choose r-j}=0$

$$ \longrightarrow \sum \limits_{m=j}^{q+j}{m\choose j}{q-m\choose r-j}=\sum \limits_{m=0}^{q}{m\choose j}{q-m\choose r-j}$$

According to $(b)$,

$$\sum \limits_{m=0}^{q}{m\choose j}{q-m\choose r-j}={q+1\choose r+1}={n+1\choose n-p+1}={n+1\choose p}$$

As expected.

---

> **Question. Are** $(2)$ **and** $(4)$ **already known?**

Comment: Poderei traduzir, mas preciso de saber o que é o 'PIF', o 'distanciamento de (n;p) do bastão em si'. Não entendo o que são essas coisas e não consigo traduzir sem saber.

Comment: Git Gud, PIF é Princípio da Indução Finita. e o distanciamento a que me refiro, é o deslocamento, a célula (n;p) sendo deslocada do restante do bastão (stick). No caso do padrão RHS, é o deslocamento  colunas acima, e no caso do padrão LHS, é o deslocamento de diagonais acima, paralelamente ao bastão original. Espero ter esclarecido, e agradeço desde já o teu interesse em colaborar.

Comment: O que é o 'bastão'? Não preciso de saber o que é RHS e LHS pois esses termos estão já em inglês.

Comment: O bastão, no caso do RHS, é uma coluna, parte de uma coluna do Triãngulo de Pascal, é a coluna que chega ao encontro da célula (n;p)

Comment: E no caso do LHS, é uma diagonal, parte de uma diagonal, é a diagonal que, vai de seu início até o encontro com a célula (n;p)

Comment: Infelizmente não conheço a tradução de 'bastão' para inglês. Uma breve pesquisa no google não ajudou. Vou apenas formatar a matemática.

Comment: Bastão? Oras, a tradução é justamente Stick :-) Ou seja, Hockey Stick é Bastão de Hóquei!

Comment: Veja, incluí uma imagem do Triângulo de Pascal com os padrões de Hockey Stick! Acredito que vá te ajudar muito a compreender melhor do que se trata, bem como a todos os demais.

Comment: sidneimv, não se preocupe com os downvotes, vamos traduzir sua pergunta. A política oficial do site permite a postagem de perguntas em outras línguas, embora elas possam ser um pouco hostilizadas.

Comment: Muito obrigado, Ian Mateus!

Comment: @IanMateus, é permitido colocar perguntas noutras línguas? Sempre me disseram o contrário...

Comment: $\text@$sidneimv, acho que devia ter tentado pelo menos pôr no Google Tradutor, e ver se fazia algum sentido.

Comment: @JMCF125 Penso que é, mas como o Ian disse, não são geralmente bem-vindas embora as regras o permitam. É recomendável colocar a tag *translation request* quando se fizer uma pergunta que não seja em inglês.

Comment: @JMCF125 é permitido caso a pessoa não saiba, outros usuários provavelmente irão editar e traduzir sua pergunta. A pessoa deve se esforçar também, Google tradutor, etc. Existe um link aqui falando sobre isso, vou procurar.

Comment: @IanMateus Estás a traduzir ou traduzo eu?

Comment: @GitGud I'm out for a while, I'll help you out when I come back. Great job!

Comment: @sidneimv Traduzi parcialmente. Optei quase sempre por uma tradução literal ao invés de uma tradução natural, mas sempre mantendo o sentido das frases. Na verdade eu continuo a achar a questão confusa, por isso vou deixar assim mesmo para ver se alguém responde e para alguma outra pessoa tentar traduzir melhor, se for caso disso.

Comment: @GitGud agradeço imensamente pela tradução parcial. Vou tentar completar a tradução. Mas não se preocupe, a questão não é confusa, não está confusa. Quem está familiarizado com o Triângulo de Pascal, facilmente entenderá tudo.

Comment: Sugiro que o fim do título seja actualizado de "(in Portuguese)" para "(translated from Portuguese)", uma vez que o texto actual já está todo em português.  I suggest to update the title, replacing "(in Portuguese)" with "(translated from Portuguese)", because the entire text is now in English.

Comment: Caro @AméricoTavares que bom vê-lo por aqui! boa dica, já alterei.

Comment: @sidneimv  Foi feito tudo com grande rapidez.

Comment: (2) is equivalent to identity (8) on the wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient

Comment: Yes, @mt_ It's very similar. I consider the question solved. Thanks.

Comment: @sidneimv de nada

Comment: sidneimv You may answer your own question, if you whish. Or ask @mt_ whether he wants to post an answer.

Comment: @IanMateus, já conseguiu encontrar o link? Gostava de tê-lo como referência quando derem “votos negativos” a questões noutras línguas.

Comment: @JMCF125 Sim, [aqui está o link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1617/what-is-the-site-etiquette-about-i-asking-and-ii-answering-questions-in-a-la). Eu esqueci de procurar na hora, me desculpe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To repeat my comment: (2) is equivalent to identity (8) on the wikipedia page [Binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).

Comment: Good job! Thanks a lot.