# Proving in Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

To PROVE 
$$\sum\limits_{r=0}^m {n+r\choose n}={n+m+1\choose n+1}$$

I tried to use ${n\choose r-1}+{n\choose r}={n+1\choose r }$
but couldn't simplify it

Comment: Are you familiar with mathematical induction?

Comment: See equation $(8)$ with $j=k$ in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient.

Comment: Mathematical induction and considering a geometric series with ratio (1+x) comes to mind. A combinatorial argument could probably also be applied seeing as it does involve binomial coefficients.

Comment: I think this identity is called the "hockey stick pattern". See  //http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/713565/are-these-two-binomial-sums-known-proven-generalization-to-the-hockey-stick-pat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the result can be obtained by a *telescoping sum* argument
$$
\sum_{r=0}^{m}{n+r\choose n} = \sum_{r=1}^{m} \left( {n+r+1\choose n+1} - {n+r\choose n+1} \right) +1 \\
= {n+m+1\choose n+1} -1 +1 = {n+m+1\choose n+1}
$$

Answer (score 1):

We have items numbered $1, 2, 3,\dots, n+m+1$.  We want to choose $n+1$ of these items. There are $n+m+1 \choose n+1$ ways to do this.

But also, the highest numbered item we pick could be any of the items $n+1, n+2, \dots, n+m+1$.  We must also pick $n$ lower numbered items.

If the highest numbered item chosen in $n+r+1$, then we have ${n+r \choose n}$ choices for the other item.  Summing over these cases ($r=0, 1,\dots, m$) gives $\sum\limits_{r=0}^m {n+r\choose n}$.

So our two different expressions for selecting the items must be equal: $\sum\limits_{r=0}^m {n+r\choose n}={n+m+1\choose n+1}$

Answer (score 0):

Using ${n\choose r-1}+{n\choose r}={n+1\choose r }$ from the question

Proof by induction:

First $m=0$
$$\sum\limits_{r=0}^0 {n+r\choose n} = {n\choose n}=1={n+1\choose n+1}$$

For $m+1$
$$\sum\limits_{r=0}^{m+1} {n+r\choose n} = \sum\limits_{r=0}^{m} {n+r\choose n} + {n+m+1\choose n} =$$
$${n+m+1\choose n+1}+{n+m+1\choose n}$$
Now using the identity from the top
$$...={n+(m+1)+1\choose n+1}$$

With this holds for $m+1$, thus this holds for all $m$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{r=0}^{m}\binom{n+r}{n}=\binom{n}{n}+\binom{n+1}{n}+\cdots+\binom{n+m}{n}\tag1$$
is the coefficient of $x^n$ in 
$$(1+x)^n+(1+x)^{n+1}+\cdots+(1+x)^{n+m}$$
$$=(1+x)^n\cdot\frac{(1+x)^{m+1}-1}{x}=\frac{(1+x)^{n+m+1}}{x}-\frac{(1+x)^n}{x}$$
Since there is no term $x^n$ in $\frac{(1+x)^n}{x}$, $(1)$ is the coefficient of $x^{n+1}$ in $(1+x)^{n+m+1}$, which is $$\binom{n+m+1}{n+1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\sum_{r\ =\ 0}^{m}{n + r \choose n} = {n + m + 1 \choose n + 1}:\ {\large ?}}$

> With $\ds{a > 1}$:
>
> \begin{align}
> &\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{r = 0}^{m}{n + r \choose n}}
> =\sum_{r\ =\ 0}^{m}\bracks{%
> \oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{n + r} \over z^{n + 1}}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}
> \\[5mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z^{n + 1}}
> \bracks{\sum_{r\ =\ 0}^{m}\pars{1 + z}^{r}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> =\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z^{n + 1}}
> \bracks{\pars{1 + z}^{m + 1} - 1 \over \pars{1 + z} - 1}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[5mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{n + m + 1} \over z^{n + 2}}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> -\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z^{n + 2}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> ={n + m + 1 \choose n + 1} -\
> \underbrace{{n \choose n + 1}}_{\ds{=\ 0}}
> \\[5mm]&=\color{#66f}{\Large{n + m + 1 \choose n + 1}}
> \end{align}