# Is row 14, column 4 for pascals triangle is 186?

Tags: abstract-algebra, binomial-coefficients

In an answer in [question in here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/713565/are-these-two-binomial-sums-known-proven-generalization-to-the-hockey-stick-pat)  diagram depicting pascals triangle ,I do not understand why in 14th row entries given are: $1, 13, 78, 186$ etc, is $186$ a typo?

Because:

$$1 \times \frac{13+1-1}1 =  13.0$$
     $$13 \times \frac{13+1-2}2
=   78.0$$
   $$ 78 \times \frac{13+1-3}3 =  286.0$$

If $186$ is not a typo, can some please explain why is this the case? Above calculations are from "Calculating a row or diagonal by itself" section of [wiki page for pascals triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle#Calculating_a_row_or_diagonal_by_itself).

It is appropriate put it as comment in the question, I joined stack exchange few minutes and I don't have the privilege to do so.

Comment: Sure, Thanks :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's a typo. Apart from your calculation, it should also be the sum of the two numbers, above, $66+220=286$.

Answer (score 2):

Row $14$ column $4$ is $\binom{13}{3} = 286$ so yes, it's a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Prime $13$ does not divide $186$ so it must be a typo.

Comment: The formula to calculate a row in pascals triangle does suggests that numbers in the row should be divisible by the 2nd number in the row (i.e., excluding 1), however, I am not sure what is the link to number being prime.

Comment: Every formula $\binom{p}{k}$ where $p$ is a prime and $1\leq k\leq p-1$ is divisible by $p$. This because $p$ divides the numerator $p!$ and does not divide the denominator $k!(p-k)!$.

Comment: Would not what you said valid for all p? does not matter if p is prime or not?

Comment: E.g. $\binom 42$ is not divisible by $4$.